How can I make this AC current switch turn on at 20mA instead of 50mA?
I've bought this AC current switch, which is sensitive to currents from 50 mA to 5 A on the single AC wire that passes inside its hole. When currents from 50 mA start to flow in the wire, it allows its output terminals to "conduct".
I need it to be sensitive to lower currents, in the range of 20 mA, so I opened it and drew the schematics of it.
While drawing it I noticed its output terminals are not isolated from the input, but I could wire an SSR to its output terminals.
Can anyone help me in what I could do to make it more sensitive to a lower current flow on the input (20 mA) in order to allow current flow on the output? I suspect if it's possible, it would be something about changing the values of R3 and/or R4.
VDA3510CTA voltage detector datasheet
Photos and schematics below:
Photos taken from Aliexpress listing here: Link





What do you mean not isolated from the input? The current transformer would provide isolation.

@Hearth indeed! I meant the whole internal circuit is connected to the output circuit… the output is not isolated from the circuit, like an opto… but you’re right… the input load is in fact isolated from the output by the transformer.

You can't easily change the basic sensitivity of the device but if you put multiple turns of the AC cable through the centre hole you can make it trip at lower currents.
For example if you put the load carrying cable through the hole twice it should trip at 25mA. If you put it through three times it would trip at 16.7mA.
As others have commented, this would also reduce the upper limit of allowable current. This is difficult to determine without knowing the number of turns on the secondary of L1.
I would expect the main limit to be excessive power in R3 or ZD2.
If R3 is reduced in value (eg 470 ohms) that would keep the maximum power the same as when used as intended with one turn on the primary. It is not obvious why R3 could not be reduced to zero.
ZD2 power dissipation is less obvious. If L1 had 1,000 turns the current in ZD2 would be about 10mA with two turns on the primary when 5A is flowing in the primary. This results in about 50mW dissipation which should be well within the capabilities of the existing device. However more than about 100mW would probably be problematic.
Additional zener diodes of the same voltage in the ZD1 and ZD3 positions may be one way to increase the allowable current although at some point the maximum dissipation in the enclosure or saturation of L1 would impose a limit. (Saturation of L1 would actually help as it would limit power dissipation automatically).

It worked!! Solved my problem!! That's perfect! Thanks!

The upper current limit will change as well

@fraxinus Good to know… so.. the upper limit will also be divided in half, if the lower limit is divided in half? In my case it’s still ok..

@fraxinus But even so it worked for my purposes, would there be any component change to allow it work without changing the upper limit?

@ Rodrigo * Change the current VDA voltage detector (3.5V) to a model with lower threshold voltage (e.g. 1.5V). These are available in  0.1V steps, beginning at 0.8V.

@Raonoke not enough - one will need to find MOSFET with lower threshold as well

@Rodrigo When you put multiple turns, the device stays the same, you just multiply the current.

@Raonoke a voltage divider (trimpot)  at the input of the VDA would do the trick?

@Rodrigo * A voltage divider would make it worse. The input voltage is at the same time also the supply voltage of the detector. What could work to increase the sensitivity is to extend the bridge rectifier at the output of the transformer to a full wave voltage doubler or replacing it entirely with a simple half wave type doubler. I don't know if there is enough room inside the case to implement the changes.

@Raonoke maybe it should be a new whole question but… is there a way for me to add/change a resistor to a trimpot, in a way where I could fine tune the exact lower current to trip the switch? I won’t draw more than 500ma in total, so even if the higher limit is lower than 5A it’s not a problem for me… there are adjustable current switches for sale, but the min adjustment in these is 200mA. I need to fine tune it between 20-25 mA…

@Rodrigo * Increase R3 somewhat to maybe 3.3k and adjust R4 (solder 100k trimmer in parallel). The VDA voltage monitor switches at 3.5V input voltage. At least 2 turns are needed for the primary winding. You can use a function generator to set the exact current through the primary.

@Raonoke it worked!! I used a 3K 2512 smd resistor in the place of R3and a 100k trimpot in parallel with R4! I had to give three turns for the primary, with only two it didn't work. I could adjust the sweet spot and now it works perfectly! Thanks so much!!
